# Can't convert model to tensorflow's lite format

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm having a trained rnn that I try to use on mobile. Problem is, when I use toco to convert my `.pb` file to `.tflite` it fails with the following error message:

```
WARNING: Config values are not defined in any .rc file: opt.
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.287s, Critical Path: 0.00s

INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco '--input_file=/Users/valentinradu/Playgrounds/char-rnn-tensorflow/remote_save/latest/graph_frz.pb' '--output_file=/Users/valentinradu/Playgrounds/char-rnn-tensorflow/remote_save/latest/graph.tflite' '--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF' '--output_format=TFLITE' '--input_type=FLOAT' '--inference_type=FLOAT' '--input_shapes=1,128:1,50,50' '--input_arrays=state_in,data_in' '--output_arrays=state_out,data_out'
2017-11-16 06:48:00.156091: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: Fill
2017-11-16 06:48:00.156811: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: Fill
2017-11-16 06:48:00.156821: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: Pack
2017-11-16 06:48:00.156829: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: Pack
2017-11-16 06:48:00.156841: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: Unpack
2017-11-16 06:48:00.156856: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: StridedSlice
2017-11-16 06:48:00.156872: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: StridedSlice
2017-11-16 06:48:00.157260: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: Pack
2017-11-16 06:48:00.157277: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:937] Converting unsupported operation: Pack
2017-11-16 06:48:00.158053: I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 40 operators, 64 arrays (0 quantized)
2017-11-16 06:48:00.158141: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:793] Check failed: indices_shape.dimensions_count() == 1 (2 vs. 1)
```

Now, I understand that this is because toco expects my model to have only one input, however, in the example I've found so far people are using 2 inputs with no problem.

Does it have to do with an operation I use inside my model?
Is this a known limitation or is it a bug?

[Here](https://github.com/valentinradu/char-rnn-tensorflow/blob/master/char_rnn/model.py) is how I build my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that unfortunately it's a limitation of the gather operator. I'll leave this here in case anybody else hits this problem in the future.

If anybody with greater experience with tensorflow, or from the team can confirm this, it would be great!.

Comment: The error lists the unsupported operations -- stuff inside the API that your model is using taht are in TensorFlow but not TensorFlow lite. It's being updated all the time, so keep trying, or keep an eye on the source code :)

Answer (score 1):

`tf.gather` takes a `indices` parameter, that is meant to be a 1-dimensional array of integers.

The error you're getting is saying that in your graph, a Gather op has an `indices` array that is 2-dimensional instead of being 1-dimensional as expected.

UPDATE: I didn't know, but it's actually legitimate to have a more-than-one-dimension indices array in Gather. Treat that as a "not implemented yet" bug in the TFLite Converter (toco).

Comment: Yes, but the expectation is because of an hardcoded value (has nothing to do with my model). Thanks for the answer!

Comment: tf.gather does support multi-d inputs, but toco's internal representation can only support the simpler 1D form of gather. Even though toco can represent some forms of gather, tflite doesn't support any form currently.